# PayU android SDk throwing error Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, payment-gateway, payu

I have integrated PayU SDK in my app, this works fine in test environment but it does not work in production environment.

I am getting this error which is breaking the flow

Value

I have debugged the hash value from server as well but it did not help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Error</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico"   href="https://static.payu.in/images/favicon.png" />
<link href="https://static.payu.in/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--[if IE 6]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
<style type="text/css"></style></head>
```

```
        <div id="header" class="clearfix">
                <div
    class="logo" >  
</div>
    </div>

<div id="container">
    <div class="paymentDetailsDiv">
        <div class="paymentDetailsHeading">An Error Occurred</div>
        <div class="paymentDetails">
            <div class="payby"></div>
            <div class="card-bg-top"></div>
            <div class="card-bg-mid">
                <div id="visamaster-container"></div>
                <div
                    style="font-size: 22px; font-weight: normal; margin-top: 15px; clear: both">
                    <h4 align="center">
                        <strong> <span style="color: #FF6600">Sorry, Some Problem
                                Occurred.</span>
                        </strong>
                    </h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-bg-bottom"></div>
            <div>
                <span style="font-size: 15px;">                                                                     </span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is because the Payu is returning a HTML, probably an error message. For example when you give an error with symfony it returns an html with the error. Try to read the HTML.

Comment: Hmm, a "payment gateway" doesn't return error response in JSON. I sometimes wonder how come such a lame payment gateway is so popular.

Comment: Payu is the worst.

Answer (score -1):

This error is coming for targetSdkVersion 25, but working fine for targetSdkVersion 23

Comment: Any other alternative to this issue because I don't think we can still publish apps with targetSdkVersion 23?